# How do you set up a perforce server to work over the internet?

Tags: perforce

I was setting up a Perforce server and only noticed options for localhosts and such. What I'm trying to do is setup up the server on a desktop machine at one household, and then be able to connect to it using the P4V Client to access the files over the internet form a another household. I no that I'll have to forward some ports and stuff but what set up files do I need to do this? I can only find info for servers that are all being run on the same network like at a business or something nothing that is over the internet. I've set up a team speak server like this where you go to connect and type in the ip address and port and then connect to the server but this dosn't have options like that, that I've seen anyway. This will be done all on Windows 7 64 bit machines. Server on desktop and clients will be on desktops and laptops. All help is appreciated and I'll be posting back with updates on what i'm doing so others can follow this as well if needed.

Answer (score 0):

The server accepts TCP/IP connections, which can be from any client machine which has TCP/IP connectivity. The Perforce server configuration for telling it which IP address and port number to listen at is the P4PORT setting: http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r12.2/manuals/cmdref/env.P4PORT.html

Since you're on a Windows machine, your server will probably be run as a Windows Service, and hence its P4PORT setting will be held in the registry section for that service. You can edit the service's configuration using a registry editor such as RegEdit, or more simply you can use 'p4 set -S Perforce P4PORT=my-host-name:my-port-number' to specify the desired IP address and port.

Then restart your Perforce service from the Services Control Panel and you're good to go!

Comment: In the server install, I have installed Server(P4D) & Command-Line (P4). Will I need to install the Proxy(P4P) as well? Defualt is that the proxy is not installed.

Comment: Also for RegEdit where would I find the registry file for the Perforce server that I can edit?
RegEdit: Computer -> HKEY_CURRENT_USER -> Software -> Perforce -> ?
What folder would it be Enviroment or P4Exp and then what file?

Comment: All you should need is P4D. Proxy is not required.